# RuntimeError while trying to build a Bayesian Linear Regression model using pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, bayesian

```
    # Adstock Transformation Formula
    def adstock_geometric(x, theta):
        x_len = data.shape[0]
        x_decay = torch.zeros_like(x)
        x_decay[0] = x[0]
        
        for i in range(1, x_len):
            x_decay[i]= x[i] + theta * x_decay[i - 1]
        return x_decay

    # Hill Transformation Formula
    def hill_transformation(x,alpha_sat,gamma_sat):
        x_len = data.shape[0]
        #x = torch.tensor(x)
        x_saturated = torch.zeros_like(x)
        x_max = torch.max(x)
        x_min = torch.min(x)
        a = torch.tensor([x_min,x_max], dtype=x.dtype)
        b = torch.tensor([1-gamma_sat,gamma_sat],dtype=x.dtype)
        inflexion = torch.dot(a,b)
        for i in range(x_len):
           x_saturated[i] = torch.pow(x[i],alpha_sat)/(torch.pow(x[i],alpha_sat)+torch.pow(inflexion,alpha_sat))
        return x_saturated
    
    
    
    def linear_regression(x, y):
        slope = pyro.sample("slope", dist.HalfNormal(2))
        intercept = pyro.sample("intercept", dist.HalfNormal(2))
        theta = pyro.sample("theta", dist.Beta(1,3))
        alpha_sat = pyro.sample("alpha_sat", dist.Gamma(3,1))
        gamma_sat = pyro.sample("gamma_sat", dist.Beta(2,2))
        with pyro.plate("data", len(y)):
            x_adstocked = adstock_geometric(x, theta)
            x_transformed = hill_transformation(x_adstocked, alpha_sat, gamma_sat)
            y_pred = slope * x_transformed + intercept
            pyro.sample("obs", dist.Normal(y_pred, 1), obs=y)
x=data['spends']
y=data['Sales']


x = torch.tensor(x.values, dtype=torch.float32)
y = torch.tensor(y.values, dtype=torch.float32)

    
nuts_kernel = NUTS(linear_regression, jit_compile=True)
mcmc_run = MCMC(nuts_kernel, num_samples=1000, warmup_steps=200)
mcmc_run.run(x, y)
```

I am running the above code for building a Bayesian Linear Regression model but encountering the error:
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor []], which is output 0 of AsStridedBackward0, is at version 92; expected version 91 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!

How do I resolve this error in the code?

Answer (score 0):

an inplace operation like this, if run codes below, then you will get the error like you posted.

```
import torch
y = torch.randn((6, 2)).requires_grad_(True)
y = y * y
y[:3, :] = y[:3, :] + y[3:, :]
y[3:, :] = y[3:, :] * y[:3, :]
y = torch.sum(y * y)
y.backward()
```

`RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [3, 2]], which is output 0 of AsStridedBackward0, is at version 2; expected version 1 instead. Hint: enable anomaly detection to find the operation that failed to compute its gradient, with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True).`

if you mark one line, it can run normally. So the problem is the **# y[3:, :] = y[3:, :] * y[:3, :]**， it inplace the value and can not backward.

```
import torch
y = torch.randn((6, 2)).requires_grad_(True)
y = y * y
y[:3, :] = y[:3, :] + y[3:, :]
# y[3:, :] = y[3:, :] * y[:3, :]
y = torch.sum(y * y)
y.backward()
```

finally, you should check some codes which use mutiply *****

If you can not find it, you should mark line and run one by one.

the solution is using clone function

```
import torch
y = torch.randn((6, 2)).requires_grad_(True)
y = y * y
y[:3, :] = y[:3, :] + y[3:, :]
k0 = y[3:, :].clone()
k1 = y[:3, :].clone()
y[3:, :] = k0 * k1
y = torch.sum(y * y)
y.backward()
```